# Appcelerator cannot build to device anymore

Tags: javascript, appcelerator

I am using Appcelerator Ti Studio and iOS SDK 1.7.2. All of a sudden I cannot transfer my app to the devise using iTunes. It has always worked but no more. Works in the simulator.

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1305, in main
    execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1066, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.2/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

I have tried the following:

1. Clean build
2. Restarted Mac
3. Created a new project and copied the resource folder into it

The only thing I can think of is that at some point I logged out my normal user and logged in with another in Ti Studio. The problems started after that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a folder in the  /resources directory with the same name as the project. 
I had the samme error, and then I renamed the folder, it all worked.

Found the solution here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/96871/another-iphone-build-on-device-error#173811

It seems only to be a problem when creating application from verson 1.7.2 of Titanium and iOS5.